# Category section in my CMS

Tags: php

I am currently developing a small CMS where the requirement is having subcategory of levels...

ROOT 
SubCategory 1

The level is just one, is there any tutorial or code which will guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question give very little info.  I assume you are using a database and want to store your pages in a tree structure?

This might help http://www.phpriot.com/articles/nested-trees-2/6

Comment: If you explain in more detail what you want you will get a better answer, I really have no idea what your looking for.